# Precise landmass outline from DEM data with QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, dem, raster-calculator, outline

I can't find a way to obtain the following (see picture below) from DEM data with QGIS -- that is, an image that would show the landmasses as white and the oceans as black from DEM data.

I've also added a screen capture of the values I get for the Virtual Raster layer I created.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: I posted an answer that does what you asked for. However, I'm not sure what you need that for and if you also considered to polygonize the raster (create contours)? Depending on what you use it for, this could be a better way.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've amended my initial question. I realize that (1) I was not clear enough, and (2) the solution might require even more formula work than I thought ... or even imagined. I'm producing a fictitious landmass from this black and white image, but would like to use QGIS to produce its initial TIFF version, so as to keep as much coastline detail as possible.

Comment: Still not clear: what is different from the first version of the question? The result you present can be generated using raster calculator as described in the solution. What do I miss?

Comment: Well, I attempted to follow your guidelines, but can't get to having the continent in white and the ocean in black. I tried different values for the sea level (1 and then -1, as well as -5, 5, and 0 for no-data), but couldn't get anything other than a completely black image. I should add that I'm very green when it comes to DEMs or QGIS -- barely knew what they were a couple of weeks ago. Thank you.

Comment: Found a simple work around to make the oceans black and the landmasses white: use Photoshop to invert the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a case for [Raster calculator](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/de/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/rasteranalysis.html?highlight=raster%20calculator#raster-calculator). Depending on the data you use (DEM), the expression to use differs.

With the DEM I used (ocean/sea as nodata value), I got the result with this epxression: `"Virtuell@1" >=0` - where `Virtuell` is the name of the [virtual raster](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/de/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/rastermiscellaneous.html?highlight=virtual%20raster#build-virtual-raster) I created of the several input layers.

Otherwise, set the condition in a way that the sea-level (ca. -1 to +1) gets another value than all other elevations: `"Virtuell@1" >=-1 and "Virtuell@1" <=1`

*Screenshot: before and after:*
[image]